# Android edittext using computer keyboard in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, keyboard, android-edittext

In Ubuntu 12.04, I'm not able to write on `edittexts` using the computer keyboard... Someone knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have also a same problem in windows7

Comment: When I was using windows 7 it worked just fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're working with the emulator here)

Even though the developer documentation says keyboard support is enabled by default it doesn't seem to be that way in SDK rev 20.  I explicitly enabled keyboard support in my emulator's config.ini file and that worked!

Add: `hw.keyboard=yes`

To: `~/.android/avd/<emulator-device-name>.avd/config.ini`

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#hardwareopts

On Mac OS and Linux you can edit all of your emulator configurations with one Terminal command:

`for f in ~/.android/avd/*.avd/config.ini; do echo 'hw.keyboard=yes' >> "$f"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Go to **AVD manager** --> click on **EDIT** ---> click on **NEW** under HARDWARE lable--> select **Keyboard support** --> set value **YES** (its default values is NO)